# Why chinese permlink can't be found on server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encoding

My wordpress permlink look likes http://example.com/?p=N ,it look likes ugly but works well.
I want to change from ugly format into pretty format,to set it in wp-admin/options-permalink.php to select postname .
[image]

An error occured.
The requested URL  was not found on this server.
[image]

1.The post can be selected in mysql console with command:

```
select * from wp_posts where post_title="查看文件系统类型的linux命令";
```

2.The post can be displayed well with url http://hwy.local/test/?p=2250 in permlink's plain form .

Why all the chinese characters can be displayed correctly in firfox and mysql console,the url with chinese charactes can't be found on my server?

For the four advices in the post here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/wordpress-slug-issue-with-non-latin-characters

1     wordpress version

WordPress 4.4.2 running Twenty Sixteen theme.

2    .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

3  encoding in mysql

```
    | Variable_name            | Value                      |
    +--------------------------+----------------------------+
    | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
    | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
    | character_set_database   | latin1                     |
    | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
    | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
    | character_set_server     | latin1                     |
    | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
    | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
    +--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Should i change character_set_database and character_set_serve from latin1 to utf8?

4 All the plugins take no effect for the chinese character permlink problem.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/universal-slugs/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/strings-sanitizer/

The pinyin plugin is more ugly than plain mode in permlink.
You will be shocked by the fact that 
pinyin is just one pair of pronounciation ,pin add yin.
there are almost thousand of chinese characters combination pronounced  as pinyin,all of them written down differently.
One form of pronounciation such as pinyin can map into thousand kinds of chinese characters combination,when you read it ,just one pronounciation;when you write it down,thousand of them can stand for pinyin.
Chinese is ideogram,pinyin means nothing for all native speakers,pinyin is used for foreigners only.
I have read more posts about it such as https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9591
The i18n permalinks problem https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9591    remains over seven years or more ,it is very significant to fix it for all non English users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case of non-latin characters in the url. Please refer to this link and try to sort out the issue : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/wordpress-slug-issue-with-non-latin-characters

Usually, this plugin fixes the issues like this : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/universal-slugs/

Other thing to be checked will be the .htaccess file with all the rules as they explain in wordpress official site.

Comment: Tried all of them , on method take effect, maybe it remains a bug for seven years.

Comment: A seven years bug?

Comment: Did you try latin1 to utf8?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Ash ,it is simple to add lines in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
.

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```